IBMi SQL stored procedures - how to set comma / decimal point in numbers
I am working on IBMi where whole number and fraction is represented by comma instead of decimal point (eg: 123,45 instead of 123.45).
This seem to be causing SQL functions to fail.
Example:
 SUBSTR(MySTRING,1,1)


SQL0104  30      12  Position 1 Token ,1 was not valid. Valid tokens: ) ,.

STRSQL provides a session value for this (Decimal point = *Comma, *Period, *Job...)
Is there header value or environment value for SQL stored procedures that would make a decimal and commas behave as US/UK users expect?

CHGJOB DECFMT(*BLANK)

What is system value QDECFMT

DSPSYSVAL QDECFMT
System value . . . . . :   QDECFMT
Description  . . . . . :   Decimal format
Decimal format . . . . :   2
where  2=J (Comma for decimal, one leading zero)

JMM: seems to be a combination of QDECFMT  and spaces that Charles mentions below.  Good catch!

You need a space between parameters... when the decimal separator is *COMMA
SUBSTR(MySTRING, 1, 1)


wow. never saw that!
...had nothing to do with comma or decimal points.

There are a number of ways to change the decimal point settings. The most global is by setting the system value, but that will affect all users, and all jobs by default. The system value is QDECFMT
 System value . . . . . :   QDECFMT                                            
 Description  . . . . . :   Decimal format                                     
                                                                           
                                                                           
 Decimal format . . . . :   1          1=blank(Period for decimal, zero        
                                         suppression)                          
                                       2=J(Comma for decimal, one leading zero)
                                       3=I(Comma for decimal, zero suppression)
                                                             

A more limited way to set this is to set it at the program level using the SQL SET OPTION statement:
SET OPTION DECMPT = *PERIOD;

And somewhere in-between is to adjust the job properties either in the job description, the submit job, or even within the job itself using CHGJOB:
CHGJOB JOB(*) DECFMT(I)

If you are using a SQL Client, you could also likely use an ODBC or JDBC setting for the connection. For JDBC, the driver property is 'decimal separator' so you would have to add decimal separator=.; to the connection string.
If you wrote an SQL stored procedure you would add the SET OPTION statement to the stored procedure code.
